# How to make a toolbar visible all the time in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I made a toolbar at the bottom of the tableview.

[image]

But when I launch the simulator, the toolbar only becomes visible when I scroll all the way down to the bottom. How can I make toolbar visible all the time?

Answer (score -1):

If you're using a Navigation Controller, make sure to tick "Shows Toolbar" and add the buttons there, not on a standalone toolbar.

In order to show only on some, you'll need 2 different views, one that will hide it and another that won't and add the following to the respective view's viewWillAppear:

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;
```

(Set to YES to hide, NO to show)

You can play around with the Simulated Metrics on the Storyboard so as to visually simulate the run-time effect by setting Bottom Bar to either None or Toolbar instead of inferred, as appropriated.

Answer (score -1):

Use below line :  `self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = false`
In `viewDidAppear()` **so that Everytime when your this viewcontroller appears** your **toolbar** will become **visible**.